# How long process is running?

Tags: linux

Is a way to check how long a proccess X is running or when it was started ? The first thought occurred to me was `ps` command, but found nothing.

Comment: you might be able to check under the /proc/<pid> directory

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The simplest way is `ps -ef`, look at the STIME column for when it was started. For a process X, use `ps -ef | grep -i X`. A more complicated method (and necessary for elapsed time) would be to use the `-o` option. Using that:

The equivalent of `ps -ef` is `ps -eo uid,pid,ppid,c,stime,tty,time,cmd`

From the man page:

> ```
>   etime      ELAPSED elapsed time since the process was started, in the
>                      form [[DD-]hh:]mm:ss.
>
>   start      STARTED time the command started. If the process was started
>                      less than 24 hours ago, the output format is
>                      "HH:MM:SS", else it is "  <mm dd" (where Mmm is a
>                      three-letter month name). See also lstart, bsdstart,
>                      start_time, and stime.
> ```

So a simple one for a process named "X" would be:

Searching commands run: `ps -eo pid,cmd,start,etime | grep -i X`
Searching executable names: `ps -eo pid,comm,start,etime | grep -i X`
Searching both: `ps -eo pid,comm,cmd,start,etime | grep -i X`

You may want to set up an alias, if you're going to be using it a lot.

Comment: Thank You very much! I did not notice that in `ps`.

Comment: Is there a way in which I could get the etime in seconds?